# ews GetSearchableMailboxes only return 1500 mailboxes paging

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I have this very simple script to get all the searchable mailboxes. I have 2000 mailboxes but this API return only 1500 every time. Wondering if the results are paged but there is no documentation regarding it.

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll";
$Service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1);
#$Service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true;
$Service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@test.com", "test123!");
$Service.Url ="https://exch2013.test.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
$Service;$m = $Service.GetSearchableMailboxes([string]::Empty,$false);
$count = 1; 
#$m.SearchableMailboxes | %{$_.SmtpAddress; $count++;}#$count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like throttling - use a paged search.
See if ECP's ediscovery search repros - if it does then its probably not an issue with your code. 
There is an example of paged searches in EWSEdtior's code (you will find the code in Github).  Find the form called EDiscoverySearch.cs.  The call to GetSearchable Mailboxes does not do paging, however another piece of code in the same form does - you can adapt it for the call to GetSearchableMailboxes.